# Flutter image_picker - pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera) crashes on ios 17+

Tags: ios, flutter, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, flutter-image-picker

When using `ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera)` the app crashes. Tried the example provided on `pub.dev` for [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker).
On an Android device, it works. On iOS 16 or below, it works.
Version image_picker 1.0.7.
I tried in different flutter versions, like 3.10.0, 3.13.9, 3.16.7.
I tried different iPhones, like XR, 13 mini, and 15 Pro Max.

Expected results:
Able to take a picture.

Actual results:
The app crashes before the camera opens.

My `info.plist` file is correct including keys `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription`, `NSCameraUsageDescription`, `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription`.

Comment: try this version image_picker: ^0.8.9

Comment: Do you have a stack trace to share?

Comment: I don't have stacktrace, because I don't have a physical macOS machine, and I only perform tests via TestFlight. The only log I have is the crashlog sent by Apple:

Exception Reason: -[NSTaggedPointerString containsObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x864ea7ad83be2bba

Last Exception Backtrace:
5   AVFCapture                     0x1c54dfd44 __47+[AVCaptureDevice isEligibleForReactionEffects]_block_invoke + 196 (AVCaptureDevice.m:3980)